# How to automatically change an img depending on boolean value in JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON file:

```
[
 {
 "id": 1,
 "availability": false
 },
 {
 "id": 2,
 "availability": true
 }
]
```

What I would like to achieve is to automatically display an image of a tick if `availability : true` and to display an image of a cross if `availability : false`.

For example these are the names of the two images:

tick.jpg 
cross.jpg

This is my code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class GetOnlinePosts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      posts: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            posts: result
          });
        },
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      );
  }
  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, posts } = this.state;
    const orderedPosts = [
      ...posts.filter(post => post.availability),
      ...posts.filter(post => !post.availability)
    ];
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error in loading</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading ...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="tiles">
            {orderedPosts.map(post => (
              <div key={post.id}>
                <div className="tile"></div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default GetOnlinePosts;
```

Unfortunately I am unable to have the images included in the with JSON. I would like the images to be within the `<div className="tile"> </div>` so any help on how to do this would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`<img src={post.availability ? 'tick.jpg' : 'cross.jpg'} />`